# JavaScript not recognized inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Someone plese tell me what I did wrong? Because, by it's self the js code works. When I put it inside php it's not recognized.

Is the if condition wrong or it's the quotes. I don't understand where is the problem.

Is just an PHP if statement that checks if we are on that page run that js code. I tried with heredoc instead of quotes but the result is the same.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/')  {
        echo '
        <script>
            window.onload = getMyLocation;

            // var ourCoords = {
            //  latitude : 47.624851,
            //  longitude: -122.52099
            // }
            var cities = {
                "1":{
                    "name":"Jacksonville",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 30.3322,
                        longitude: 81.6557
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/jacksonville/"
                },
                "2":{
                    "name":"SF Peninsula",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 37.4615,
                        longitude: 122.3108
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/sfpeninsula/"
                },
                "3":{
                    "name":"Atlanta",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 33.7490,
                        longitude: 84.3880
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/atlanta/"
                },
                "4":{
                    "name":"Maryland",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 39.0458,
                        longitude: 76.6413
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/maryland/"
                },
                "5":{
                    "name":"Houston",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 29.7604,
                        longitude: 95.3698
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/huston/"
                },
                "6":{
                    "name":"San Jose",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 37.20,
                        longitude: 121.54
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/san-joseeast-bay/"
                },
                "7":{
                    "name":"New Jersey",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 40.0583,
                        longitude: 74.4057
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/new-jersey/"
                },
                "8":{
                    "name":"Seattle",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 47.6062,
                        longitude: 122.3321
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/seattle/"
                },
                "9":{
                    "name":"Dallas",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 32.7767,
                        longitude: 96.7970
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/dallas/"
                },
                "10":{
                    "name":"Pennsylvania",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 41.2033,
                        longitude: 77.1945
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/pennsylvania/"
                },
                "11":{
                    "name":"Chicago",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 41.8781,
                        longitude: 87.6298
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/chicago/"
                },
                "12":{
                    "name":"New Jersey – North",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 40.0583,
                        longitude: 74.4057
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/new-jersey-north/"
                },
                "13":{
                    "name":"Orlando",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 28.5383,
                        longitude: 81.3792
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/orlando/"
                },
                "14":{
                    "name":"San Jose",
                    "coords":{
                        latitude : 25.7617,
                        longitude: 80.1918
                    },
                    "url":"http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/miamibrowardwp/"
                }
            };


            function getMyLocation() {
                // check if the browser supports Geolocation API
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    // we call the getCurrentPosition method and pass in a handler function, displayLocation
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayErrors);
                } else {
                    alert("No geolocation support by your browser!");
                }
            }


            // Function called when the browser has a location
            // position contains the latitude and longitude of your location
            function displayLocation(position) {
                // grab the latitude and longitude of your location from the position object and his .coords property
                var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

                // var div = document.getElementById("location");
                // div.innerHTML = "You are at Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude;

                //var km = computeDistance(position.coords, ourCoords);

            var arrKMs = [];
            for (var city in cities)
            {
                //var cityName=cities[city].name;
                var cityCoords=cities[city].coords;

                arrKMs[city] = computeDistance(position.coords, cityCoords);
                var kmm= computeDistance(position.coords, cities[city].coords); 
            }

            //get minimal value
            var index = 0;
            var value = 100000000;
            for (var ind in arrKMs)
            {//alert(ind + " - " + arrKMs[ind]);
                if (parseFloat(arrKMs[ind]) < value)
                {
                    value = arrKMs[ind];
                    index = ind;
                }
            }
            window.location.replace(cities[index].url);
            //alert(cities[index].url);
                // var distance = document.getElementById("distance");
                // distance.innerHTML = "You are " + arrKMs[index] + " km from our Company";

                // var url_address = document.getElementById("url_address");
                // url_address.innerHTML = "web site found: " + cities[index].url;

                // showMap(position.coords);
            }


            // Handler which is passed an error by the Geolocation API
            function displayErrors(error) {
                var errorTypes = {
                    0: "Unknown error",
                    1: "Permision denied by user",
                    2: "Position is not available... ",
                    3: "Request timed out"
                };

                // using the error.code property, we assign one of those strings(0, 1, 2, 3) to a new variable, errorMessage
                var errorMessage = errorTypes[error.code];

                // In the case of errors zero and two, there is sometimes additional information in the error.message property, so we add that to our errorMessage string
                if (error.code == 0 || error.code == 2) {
                    errorMessage = errorMessage + " " + error.message;
                }
                var div = document.getElementById("location");
                // we add the message to the page to let the user know
                div.innerHTML = errorMessage;
            }


            // This function takes two coordinates, a start coodinate and a destination coordinate, and returns the distance in kilometers between them
            function computeDistance(startCoords, destCoords) {
                var startLatRads = degreesToRadians(startCoords.latitude);
                var startLongRads = degreesToRadians(startCoords.longitude);
                var destLatRads = degreesToRadians(destCoords.latitude);
                var destLongRads = degreesToRadians(destCoords.longitude);

                // radius of the Earth in km
                var Radius = 6371; 
                var distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(startLatRads) * Math.sin(destLatRads) +
                    Math.cos(startLatRads) * Math.cos(destLatRads) * 
                    Math.cos(startLongRads - destLongRads)) * Radius;

                return distance;
            }


            function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
                var radians = (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
                return radians;
            }

            var map;
            function showMap(coords) {
                var googleLatAndLong = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.latitude,coords.longitude);
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: googleLatAndLong,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
                map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

                // add the user marker
                var title = "Your Location";
                var content = "You are here: " + coords.latitude + ", " + coords.longitude;
                addMarker(map, googleLatAndLong, title, content);
            }


            // shows with a pin where are you
            function addMarker(map, latlong, title, content) {
                var markerOptions = {
                    position: latlong,
                    map: map,
                    title: title,
                    clickable: true
                };
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

                var infoWindowOptions = {
                    content: content,
                    position: latlong
                };

                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infoWindowOptions);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, \'click\', function() {
                    infoWindow.open(map);
                });
            }
        </script>';
```

}

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` [From the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) _"The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'."_ Which means you are comparing `http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/` to `index.php/locations/` so, your if clause is doing what you are telling it to do, doing some basic debugging and research is essential to coding.

Comment: Add `else { echo "ERROR: URL is " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; }` after `if` for simple debugging

Comment: I get the same  ERROR: URL is index.php/locations/ and still doesn't work with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'http://us-airquality.com/index.php/locations/')` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == 'index.php/locations/')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't typically include the domain, unless you're using a proxy server. Try this for your `if` condition instead:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/index.php/locations/') {
```

Comment: Thank you @Zac and for all of you that help me.

Comment: You're welcome! An even better way would be `if ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] == '/locations/') {`